# How to save input values in a Backbone model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Currently I'm running into the situation when I need to grab one value from selected option and value of one input and save it in a backbone model and then save on a server. Here's my markup:

```
<select id="select" multiple size=5>
    <option value="Room" name="room">Room</option>
    <option value="Teacher" name="teacher">Teacher</option>
    <option value="Group" name="group">Group</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="name">
<button type="button" class="save">Save</button>
```

By clicking on a save button I want to store current two values in a model. I tried plugin ModelBinder for Backbone, but I think I just use it in a wrong way.

```
var CreateEditView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',

    template: editResourceTpl,

    events: {
        'click .save': 'save',
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.modelBinder = new Backbone.ModelBinder();
    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.append(this.template()); 
        this.modelBinder.bind(this.model, this.el);

        return this;
    },

    save: function () {
        var isNewModel = this.model.isNew();

        this.model.once('sync', function () {
            if (isNewModel) {
                vm.mediator.publish('ResourceSaved', this.model);
            }
        }, this);

        this.model.save();
    }    
});
```

Can someone please give me a right direction of how can I do this? I just need to gather 2 values from form (1 from a selected option and 1 from input), then store it in a model and save on server (and yet pass this model through mediator). How can I use ModelBinder plugin here in a correct way to achieve this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`option` does not have property `name`. You should assign `name` to `select`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option